# Get specific data in table format using bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a text file, `test.txt`, with this content:

```
a:b:c:u
e:f:g:h
i:j:k:l
m:n:v:w
q:r:s:t
```

I want to make a bash script which will cut data from text files like this, for example:

```
./run.sh test.txt 3 2 5 3

j:k
n:v
r:s
```

The first parameter is the file location, the second is the first row I want, the third is the column of that row, the fourth is the last row, and the last parameter is the column of that row.

I started to work on this script but I have gotten stuck.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
    echo "The first parameter doesn't exist."
    exit 2
elif [ "$#" -ne 5 ]; then
    echo "Given parameter is less than five."
    exit 1
else
    i=0
    while read line; do
        test $((++i)) = $2 && cut -d':' -f$3
    done
fi
```

How should I complete my code to work as described above?

Comment: Change `-ne` to `-lt` OR change "less than" to "not equal to"

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and clarify a bit? How do you define columns? By the `:`? If so, why is the 5th column `j` and not empty since there are less than 5 columns per line.  You seem to want to combine both a field-based (column-based) approach and a character-based one (where 5 refers to the 5th character, not the 5th column). Also, does this have to be in bash? Bash is an awful tool for text parsing. It can do it, but it is hard to get right, the syntax is complex and it is very slow.

Comment: Sidenote: In terms of X and Y, the arguments are Y1 X1 Y2 X2, which I find confusing. They might be less confusing as domain and range (X1 X2 Y1 Y2) or start coordinate to end coordinate (X1 Y1 X2 Y2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could possibly manage like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ! -f "$1" ]]; then
  echo "oops, no such file"
  exit 1
elif [[ $# -lt 5 ]]; then
  echo "oops, not enough params"
  exit 2
fi
sed -n "$2,$4p" "$1" | cut -d ':' -f$3-$5
```

#### Notes

- `sed -n` call `sed` in quiet mode - no printing until we ask for something
- `"$2,$4p" "$1"` print lines from `$2` until `$4` inclusive in file `$1`
- `| cut -d ':' -f$3-$5` print fields `$3` to `$5` inclusive from whatever `sed` printed